# Displaying links within a body of text from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, stripslashes

I am building a personal blog from scratch and I am having trouble with getting my links to display correctly when outputting the text body from MySQL.

For example;
I have a link embedded about 200 words into a blog post, when I call the blog post from the database the link doesn't display correctly. I have tried using `stipslashes()` and `htmlentities()` and neither of those are working.

Here is my code to save the blog post to the DB:

```
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    die($problem);
}
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_POST['addBlog'])) { //form submitted?

// get form values, escape them and apply the check_input function
$title = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$category = $link->real_escape_string(check_input($_POST['category'], "You must choose a category."));
$content = $link->real_escape_string(check_input($_POST['blogContent'], "You can't publish a blog with no blog... dumbass."));
$date = $link->real_escape_string(check_input($_POST['pub_date'], "What day is it foo?"));


mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) OR DIE (mysqli_error());
// select the db
mysqli_select_db ($link, $db_name) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysqli_error($db_name));

 // our sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO pub_blogs (title, date, category, content) VALUES ('$title', '$date', '$category', '$content');";

//save the blog     
mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysqli_error($link));

if (!mysqli_error($link)) 
{
    print "<p> Blog Successfully Published! </p>";
}
}
```

And here is my code to display the blog post: **This is where the trouble is**

```
            // Grab the data
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM pub_blogs") or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysqli_error($link));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
            $id = $link->real_escape_string($row['id']);
            $title = $link->real_escape_string($row['title']);
            $date = $link->real_escape_string($row['date']);
            $category = $link->real_escape_string($row['category']);
            $content = $link->real_escape_string($row['content']);

            $id = stripslashes($id);
            $title = stripslashes($title);
            $date = stripslashes($date);
            $category = stripslashes($category);
            $content = stripslashes($content);

        }
        echo "<div class='blog_entry_container'>";
        echo "<span class='entry_date'><a href='#'>" .$date. "</a> - </span><span class='blog_title'><a class='blogTitleLink' href='#'>" .$title. "</a></span>"; 
        echo "<p>" .$content. "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
```

**The issue lies within the `$content` variable**

Comment: I think you need addslashes instead of stripslashes

Comment: no, that just adds more slashes. I've already tried this.

Comment: can you paste what you are getting into $content ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? I don't want to paste anything in my database...

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to prepared statements and get rid of all that escaping and slashing stuff.

That should get your original blog post correctly in the database but now you have a problem: You should use `htmlspecialchars` to output stuff to html (to avoid problems like texts turning into tags, etc.) but that would mangle up your links.

A solution for that problem would be to use a mark-up language (like markdown) to translate your links to html links on the fly. Also see this [blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/potential-markup-and-editing-choices/) about the mark-up for questions and answers on SO.

An alternative would be to write the content completely in html and get rid of the surrounding `<p>` tags but that would only work if you (or trusted users) are the only ones who can write blog entries. Or find a good way to clean / validate your input of course...

Comment: So if I switch my queries to prepared statements and get rid of all the escaping and slashing stuff will my links appear correctly?

Comment: @Ty Bailey If your links are html, yes, but then you can invalidate your html easily by using characters like `<`, `>`, etc. in your content.